# Rails 4 - update form without submit (gem)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Is there a Gem available with Rails that I can use to have real-time changes posted when users type in a field, so they do not have to hit submit?

I assume JS will be needed and the use of an on-change event, but looking for a gem that makes my life easy so I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: typeahead is one of them https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead, not a gem, but a jQuery plugin

Comment: Do you want it to submit every keystroke, like a search field? In that case typeahead would be a good choice. Or do you want it to submit what you have typed when they hit Enter or blur the text field? You could do that with a couple of lines of javascript, or possibly using browser storage.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of Rails now, and it's called ActionCable. But you will have to write code anyway, because there are so many ways you can use it.